# Sklearn Random Forest Model Not Removing Header from Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to feed the data below into a random forest algorithm using sklearn.

Data (presented as a csv):

```
id,CAP,astroturf,fake_follower,financial,other,overall,self-declared,labels
3039154799,0.7828265255249504,0.1,1.8,1.4,3.2,1.4,0.4,1
390617262,1.0,0.8,1.4,1.0,5.0,5.0,0.2,0
4611389296,0.7334998320027682,0.2,0.6,0.1,1.8,1.1,0.0,1
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

master_training_set_path = "data_bank/cleaning_data/master_training_data_id/master_train_one_hot.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(master_training_set_path)
labels = np.array(df["labels"].values)

train, test, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(df, labels,
                                                      stratify=labels,
                                                      test_size=0.3)
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, bootstrap=True, max_features='sqrt')

# this is the problematic line
model.fit(train, train_labels)
```

The problematic line is the last one and when I run it, it returns the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\random_forest.py", line 39, in 
<module>
    model.fit(train, train_labels)
  File "path\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py", line 247, in fit
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse="csc", dtype=DTYPE)
  File "path\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 434, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'self-declared'
```

I've tried making sure that the 'train' and 'train_label' variables are numpy 2d arrays, but I still get the same error

My confusion comes from the fact that the "self declared" feature is not a value but is the name of a certain feature in my dataset. Why isn't sklearn dropping the headers before training the data?

Comment: The code runs for me (perhaps take another look at your csv file). Side note: be aware that `train` and `test` contain the labels.

Comment: Okay, took a look at the csv file, there were some small issues. Namely the header being in the dataset. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works on scikit-learn version: `0.23.1`. You can try to update if you are using the older version with the following:

```
conda install scikit-learn=0.23.1
```

The problem could be that you are supplying `df` to `train_test_split`. This will work, however, it creates problem for the model because  `train` and `test` dataframes (with headers) are created instead of feature matrices. Therefore, you can try to replace:

```
train, test, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(df, labels,
                                                      stratify=labels,
                                                      test_size=0.3)
```

with this:

```
df.drop(['labels'],axis=1,inplace=True) #you have labels in the training set as well.
train, test, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(df.values, labels,
                                                      stratify=labels,
                                                      test_size=0.3)
```